# How do you select by content in jquery and change the css?

Tags: jquery, css

I have these buttons that have been generated with javascript and I can't change how they are created but I want to add an individual active state color for each button. I am trying to do it in jquery but my knowledge is poor. Wondering if anyone can help me?

```
nav id="menu">
<a href = "#" class="active">1</a>
<a href = "#" class="active">2</a>
<a href = "#" class="active">2</a>
</nav>


$("a:contains('1')").css("active", "green");
$("a:contains('2')").css("active", "red");
$("a:contains('3')").css("active", "blue");
```

Comment: [The DOCS for .css()](https://api.jquery.com/css/) would give you loads of info! PS: there's no such `"active"` property in CSS in general. Unless you meant to go for... `:active` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active

Comment: Also, why don't you use CSS `:nth-child(n)`  instead of jQuery? Does really the *contents* of that element make such importance?

Comment: how to do I select the button by content though. I tried just filling it with colour and that doesn't work either.
.css('background-color', 'red');

Comment: I want the button with the text inside "1" to be green the one with the text "2" to be red etc. I can't do this in the css style sheet because there is no way to target the button based on it's content. The id and classes are all the same. Roko.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gc25z6nk/ exactly like you're doing it already. All it takes is to know how to use the `.css()` method correctly. Either `.css("property", "value")` or `.css({property: "value", otehrProperty: "value"})` - and no, there's no such `"active"` property in CSS.

Comment: oh, it didn't seem to work for me though it works in fiddle for you. I will have to figure out why it isn't working.

Comment: I explained in my edited comments.

Comment: PS. it's also always the best idea not to use styles in JS, but to define a special class in CSS and use JS only to toggle that class from such element. For jQuery explore the `.toggleClass()` or `.addClass()` or `removeClass()`. You can do the same in plain JavaScript - called `Element.classList` with the methods `.add() / .remove() / .toggle()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: Yes, I think this would work better. Will see if I can get that working. Thank you Roko.

Comment: You're very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Change "active" to "background-color" or "color". Whatever you want to change.
You can also consider [adding/removing](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css_classes.asp) classes this might be a cleaner way to do it.

```
<nav id="menu">
   <a href = "#" class="active">1</a>
   <a href = "#" class="active">2</a>
   <a href = "#" class="active">2</a>
</nav>


$("a:contains('1')").css("background-color", "green");
$("a:contains('2')").css("background-color", "red");
$("a:contains('3')").css("background-color", "blue");
```

Comment: That might be a good idea.
So would be something like this? I have not used jquery before.
$("a:contains('1')").removeClass("active").addClass("one");

Comment: @TamTaminToronto exactly, as I said in my comment, try always to use classes instead of putting styles definitions in JS code! There's also no need to define two special classes. Just one special, the other styles can be defined as defaults.